# Clicking on div isn't opening modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, modal-dialog

I have a bunch of divs and clicking on any of them should open a modal that I've hardcoded into my html. The plan is to click on a specific Category, the modal opens, and it shows the sub-categories (Training Courses) that are associated with that particular Category. But for right now, I'm most concerned about getting an actual modal to appear on click. In my console I can see that the modal is getting clicked but there's no indication elsewhere that the modal's showing up (i.e. it doesn't appear to be super small or invisible).

Any thoughts on this one?

#### JS snippet:

```
        // irrelevant code
        ]).then(axios.spread((cat, lib, admn) => {
            _categories = cat.data.d.results;
            _library = lib.data.d.results;

            this.loadCategories();
            this.loadCourses();
        })).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    loadCategories(){
        let categs = _categories;

        let htmlElems = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < categs.length; i++) {
                htmlElems += "<div class='cat-box cat-num-" + i + "'>" + categs[i].Title + "</div>";
            }

        let container = document.querySelector("div.top-training");
        container.innerHTML = htmlElems;
        console.log(container);

    }

    loadCourses(){ // Training Library

        let crs = _library
            .map(x => {
                return x.Title;
            }).sort();

        this.populateCategory(crs, "div.top-training");
    }

    populateCategory(arrObj, parentTarget){
        arrObj = arrObj.filter((v, p) => arrObj.indexOf(v) == p);

        $.each(arrObj, function(idx, val) {

            let targetDiv = $(parentTarget).hasClass(".cat-box");


            let modalTrigger = $('<div />', {
                'class': 'cat-box',
                'data-category': val,
                'data-target': '#modal-id',
                'data-toggle': 'modal',
                'text': val
            });

            targetDiv.append(modalTrigger);
       // irrelevant code here
        });
    }
```

#### index.js

```
import AllCoursesComponent from './path/allCourses';

let allComp = new AllCoursesComponent();

$(document).on("click", '.cat-box', function(val) {
    console.log('.cat-box clicked')
    let cat  = $(this).data('category')

    $(".training-titles-ul").empty();
    let titles = allComp.getPayload().filter(x => x.Title === cat);

});
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="top-training"></div>

<!----- Modal ----->
    <div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal stuff here -->   
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap for the modal? You could try adding an anchor with a `data-toggle` attribute. Similar to this `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-id"`

Comment: Hey @Truextacy, actually I am using bootstrap for the modal. Under `data-toggle`, would I change it to `#modal-id` to make it the same as `data-target`?

Comment: No, you would only put the id under the `data-target`. Whatever element you want to have trigger your modal should have those attributes, and the id should point to the modal you want to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can toggle a bootstrap modal for your situation

```
<div class="top-training" id="traning1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-id">Here</div>

<!----- Modal ----->
    <div class="modal" id="modal-id" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <!-- modal stuff here -->   
       here
      </div> 
    </div>
```

To handle the dynamic data that you need to pass in to that modal, I would probably attach an event handler to each div that sets the modal's content. 
Example:

```
$('#traning1').on('click',function(){
   $("#someIdForModalContent").text('I am some content.');
});
```

Comment: Hey, I made the changes but to no luck. Could something be off with the `populateCategory()` function?

Comment: Could you post your code in a jsfiddle and I'll take a look?

Comment: Here's a [Plunker link](https://embed.plnkr.co/QAVYO6yyzwHun3FCdFgb/). I went with Plunker to include the second .js file.

Comment: You have the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes on your modal element. They should be on the element that you wish to have open your modal. Take a look at the jsfiddle I posted. That plunker is not working for me..

Comment: Ah I missed that. I'll make the changes and will get back to you. **Update:** Yep, that was the problem. Thank you!